# how to print sympy matrix....why new line?

Tags: sympy

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad English!

how to print sympy matrix....why new line?

return?

〇I will try to make new def.

def myPrintMatrix(Matrix1,Matrix2)

print???????

return

Please give me advice

```py
    from sympy import *
    def myPrintMatrix():
        return Matrix([11,12]), \
               Matrix([21,22])
    print(myPrintMatrix())
    # (Matrix([
    # [11],
    # [12]]), Matrix([
    # [21],
    # [22]]))
    ################################
    # I want bellow.
    # Matrix([11, 12]),
    # Matrix([21, 22])
    # or 
    # Matrix([11, 12]),Matrix([21, 22])
    # why print? [12]]), Matrix([
```

Comment: You're printing a tuple. Just print each matrix separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An objective for the str representation of SymPy objects is to have something that looks good and that can be copied and pasted to recreate the object. The newline is printed after `Matrix([` so that what you see is mostly the uncluttered matrix elements:

```
>>> randMatrix(2,2)
Matrix([
[44, 73],
[97, 57]])
```

instead of

```
Matrix([[44, 73],[97, 57]])
```

since the latter loses the 2x2 structural appearance.

If you don't like this, capture the string output and print it by replacing newlines with a space

```
>>> print(str(_).replace('\n',''))
Matrix([[44, 73], [97, 57]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what bothers you:

```
In [353]: Matrix([1,2])
Out[353]: 
⎡1⎤
⎢ ⎥
⎣2⎦

In [354]: Matrix([[1,2]])
Out[354]: [1  2]

In [355]: _353.shape
Out[355]: (2, 1)

In [356]: _354.shape
Out[356]: (1, 2)
```

Regardless of what you supply, `Matrix` makes a 2d object.  It's docs should discuss this.

`Array` can be 1d:

```
In [358]: Array([1,2])
Out[358]: [1  2]

In [359]: _.shape
Out[359]: (2,)
```

I'm more familiar with `numpy's` distinction between `ndarray` and `matrix`, but `sympy` seems to follow a similar (but not identical) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I try

```
from sympy import *
def myPrintNewline(myInput):
    return str(myInput).replace('\n','')

def myTest(myT0, myT1):
    return Matrix(myT0),Matrix(myT1)

myInput=[[44,73],[97,57]]
myOutput=myTest(myInput[0],myInput[1])
print("#10-line",myOutput)
print("#11-line",myPrintNewline(myOutput))
print("#12-line",myOutput[0])
print("#13-line",myOutput[1])
bb=Matrix([
[44, 73],
[97, 57]])
print("#17-line",bb)
#
# #10-line (Matrix([
# [44],
# [73]]), Matrix([
# [97],
# [57]]))
# #11-line (Matrix([[44],[73]]), Matrix([[97],[57]]))
# #12-line Matrix([[44], [73]])
# #13-line Matrix([[97], [57]])
# #17-line Matrix([[44, 73], [97, 57]])
```